# SHA256 Digest Signature with Node-Forge

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl, cryptography, lets-encrypt

I'm building a Node.js ACMEv2 client and trying to rely only on a single cryptography library to keep the code simple. The native Node Crypto module does not support CSR, so I had to use [Node-Forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge). So far everything works but I'm having a hard time finding the equivalent code using Node-Forge:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update(`${requestBase64Url.protected}.${requestBase64Url.payload}`, 'utf8');
const signature = signer.sign(this.keys.accountKey.privatePem, 'base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=/g, '');
console.log(signature);
```

The output is:

> oZpJuZlNgU48t8l-39V1LUZScOPHTFzHDWYT6ttf1KBGnm6jNuGkogwc0QiANrt5h5z6mp0Wz3rPz7etxjby_znQsGuaGdxvtVDf30_6j0mN-Rh7OXkS489JK6kDSQRbhpoyulb75QZyhDoA2pbmqyPc6HnfnQ2gUGr8HZf3K_LnfXCAX807MAzXd_bOx2dE0NbnwoVQQgGG1u5s7Q9-DY1WNjolYmkTt_skNoXgbAKZwj-8x6oSbfGk5_7-mbuEXcxUAJuXmGQsHrHAp7lKBZ9ZhTyZUlZjEhfRYb7cMYHSAJccalMPC5y5uzrIQYILhGtuDcXBsY1rCanJw6eRqg

I can also achieve the same output using the following OpenSSL (and encoding the results into base64url):

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign account.key -out signature.sha256 signature.b64
```

How can I get the same result using the [Node-Forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) module? I tried the following without any luck:

```
let messageDigest = forge.md.sha256.create();
messageDigest.update(`${requestBase64Url.protected}.${requestBase64Url.payload}`, 'utf8');
const accountKey = await forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(this.keys.accountKey.privatePem);
request.signature = accountKey.sign(messageDigest);
```

The output is:

> wqHCmknCucKZTcKBTjzCt8OJfsOfw5V1LUZScMOjw4dMXMOHDWYTw6rDm1_DlMKgRsKebsKjNsOhwqTCogwcw5EIwoA2wrt5wofCnMO6wprCnRbDj3rDj8OPwrfCrcOGNsOyw785w5DCsGvCmhnDnG_CtVDDn8OfT8O6wo9Jwo3DuRh7OXkSw6PDj0krwqkDSQRbwobCmjLCulbDu8OlBnLChDoAw5rClsOmwqsjw5zDqHnDn8KdDcKgUGrDvB3Cl8O3K8Oyw6d9cMKAX8ONOzAMw5d3w7bDjsOHZ0TDkMOWw6fDgsKFUEIBwobDlsOubMOtD34Nwo1WNjolYmkTwrfDuyQ2woXDoGwCwpnDgj_CvMOHwqoSbcOxwqTDp8O-w77CmcK7woRdw4xUAMKbwpfCmGQsHsKxw4DCp8K5SgXCn1nChTzCmVJWYxIXw5Fhwr7DnDHCgcOSAMKXHGpTDwvCnMK5wrs6w4hBwoILwoRrbg3DhcOBwrHCjWsJwqnDicODwqfCkcKq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to:

1. https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/647
2. https://repl.it/repls/RipeLatestOctal

Basically, forge encodes the signature into a binary string which must be decoded using the following code:

```
request.signature = Buffer.from(forge.util.binary.raw.decode(accountKey.sign(messageDigest)));
```