# Encrypt in Kotlin, How do I decrypt this using crypto in Angular app?

Tags: java, typescript, kotlin, encryption, cryptography

I am new at encrypting & decrpyting aspect of coding. I am trying to decrypt the string outputted from Kotlin using crypto (AES-GCM) on my Angular app (Typescript). But the outputted string is wrong. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here's how the string encrypted.

**Kotlin:**

```
import android.util.Base64
import java.io.IOException
import java.security.*
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

class EncryptionUtils {
    companion object {
        private const val CHARACTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8"
        private const val CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
        private const val AES_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "AES"
        private const val GCM_NONCE_LENGTH = 12
        private const val GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 128

        fun encrypt(plain: String, key: String): String {
            val encryptedBytes = encrypt(plain.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), key)
            return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
        }

        fun encrypt(message: ByteArray, key: String): ByteArray {
            val keyBytes = generateKey(key)
            val ivBytes = generateRandomIV(GCM_NONCE_LENGTH)

            val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION)
            val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, AES_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM)
            val gcmParameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH, ivBytes)

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec)
            val encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message)

            val result = ByteArray(ivBytes.size + encrypted.size)
            System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, result, 0, ivBytes.size)
            System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, result, ivBytes.size, encrypted.size)

            return result
        }

        private fun generateKey(key: String): ByteArray {
            val keyBytes = key.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
            md.update(keyBytes)
            return md.digest()
        }

        private fun generateRandomIV(length: Int): ByteArray {
            val ivBytes = ByteArray(length)
            val random = SecureRandom()
            random.nextBytes(ivBytes)
            return ivBytes
        }
    }
}
```

```
private suspend fun sendErrorReportPostRequest(token: String, errorReport: ErrorReport): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {
            val encryption = EncryptionUtils.Companion
            val key = "MYAPP${errorReport.file.nameWithoutExtension}"
            val api = ApiUploadDatabasePostRequest(
                s3Link = errorReport.file.name,
                password = encryption.encrypt("some-password"  ?: "", key),
            )
            result.isSuccess
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.e(e)
            false
        }
    }
```

Sample output data from Kotlin:

```
salt = "MYAPP"
secretKey = "MYAPP11948-Sep022023145358"
encryted = 'a4b67Rufd5nODsjgdWllLlgxVJQewy+nLNZxlDM57JxA7NJvwv5Sfb26qYtkYY0JZF3iNaMuN6RBFANEXHE44w=='
```

Here's how I try to decrypt:

**Angular App (Typescript):**

```
async decryptPass() {
    
    let secretKey = "MYAPP11948-Sep022023145358"
    const encryted = 'a4b67Rufd5nODsjgdWllLlgxVJQewy+nLNZxlDM57JxA7NJvwv5Sfb26qYtkYY0JZF3iNaMuN6RBFANEXHE44w=='
    const secretKeyBytes = this.generateKey(secretKey);

    const keyBuffer = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'raw',
      secretKeyBytes, {
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        length: 128
      },
      false,
      ['decrypt']
    )

    const encryptedString = atob(encryted)

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(encryptedString.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < encryptedString.length; i++) {
      byteArray[i] = encryptedString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const ivBytes = byteArray.slice(0, 12);
    const encryptedBytes = byteArray.slice(12);

    const cleartext = await crypto.subtle.decrypt({
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        "iv": ivBytes,
    }, keyBuffer, encryptedBytes);

    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(cleartext))
    // Expected output: 8d818916-2cd3-4d72-aa7a-5c73783ba16a
  }

generateKey(key: string) {
    const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
    const byteArray = textEncoder.encode(key);
    
    let md = forge.md.sha256.create();
    md.update(byteArray);
    
    return md.digest()
  }
```

This shows an error `TypeError: Key data must be a BufferSource for non-JWK formats`. Can somebody help and enlighten me about this decrypting? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is the salt applied in the Kotlin code? The use of a fast digest without salt might be an invitation for many hackers.

Comment: That's also my question but my friend said that it is hard coded. Is there a way to decrypt that?

Comment: Post complete test data: non-productive key, plaintext and ciphertext. Currently the plaintext is missing.

Comment: The plaintext is `8d818916-2cd3-4d72-aa7a-5c73783ba16a` which is the expected output of the decryption.

Comment: This data is not consistent. The first 12 bytes of the encrypted data are the nonce. If you use this nonce to encrypt the posted plaintext with the posted key, you get a different ciphertext than the one you posted. Post consistent (non-productive) test data, i.e. plaintext, key and ciphertext, which results from encrypting this plaintext with this key!

Comment: What does the first 12 bytes used as the Initialization Vector (IV)? Can't it be extracted and use as IV for decryption and the remaining bytes are the encrypted plaintext?

Comment: Still waiting for test data that can be reproduced with the Kotlin code.

Comment: based on following post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505465/sha256-digest-signature-with-node-forge.md.sha256 is creating a string, it needs to be a Buffer

Comment: Regarding the JS code: Apply only one library and not different ones, this shortens the code and avoids unnecessary conversions (and a number of conversion bugs). Also, the key size is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not that hard to post consistent test data that can be used to test the JavaScript code. With the following passphrase and plaintext:

```kotlin
val secretKey = "MYAPP11948-Sep022023145358"
val plaintext = "8d818916-2cd3-4d72-aa7a-5c73783ba16a";
```

and the nonce from the ciphertext you posted:

```kotlin
val IV = Base64.decode("a4b67Rufd5nODsjg", Base64.NO_WRAP) // 0x6b86faed1b9f7799ce0ec8e0, 12 bytes
```

the shared Kotlin code produces the following Base64 encoded ciphertext:

```
a4b67Rufd5nODsjgDxCP59gxvmy1RfXoLs+A9hLe/6IsAA1OcvtPil0YGFqo2zvYWtZX+xq3B9vNDbVotLZuqw==
```

As already described in the comments, the hashing can be done with WebCrypto, so that the *forge* library is not needed. Also, as in the Kotlin code, a 32 bytes key must be applied (i.e. AES-256). This changes your code to:

```js
(async () => {
async function decryptPass() {
    
    let secretKey = "MYAPP11948-Sep022023145358"
    const encryted = 'a4b67Rufd5nODsjgDxCP59gxvmy1RfXoLs+A9hLe/6IsAA1OcvtPil0YGFqo2zvYWtZX+xq3B9vNDbVotLZuqw=='
    const secretKeyBytes = await generateKey(secretKey);

    const keyBuffer = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'raw',
        secretKeyBytes, {
            name: 'AES-GCM',
            length: 256 // Fix key size
        },
        false,
        ['decrypt']
    )

    const encryptedString = atob(encryted)

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(encryptedString.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < encryptedString.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = encryptedString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const ivBytes = byteArray.slice(0, 12);
    const encryptedBytes = byteArray.slice(12);

    const cleartext = await crypto.subtle.decrypt({
        name: 'AES-GCM',
        "iv": ivBytes,
    }, keyBuffer, encryptedBytes);

    console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(cleartext)) // Expected output: 8d818916-2cd3-4d72-aa7a-5c73783ba16a
}

async function generateKey(key) {
    return await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(key)); // apply digest() from WebCrypto
}
  
await decryptPass();
})();
```

that, with these changes, successfully decrypts the ciphertext generated by the Kotlin code.